# Getting each of the CPU cores usage via terminal in MacOS

Tags: macos, cpu

I need to get the list of each of CPU cores usage with one command in macOS terminal.

I have been searching the web for a few hours, but all that I was able to find were two variants, both of which are not what I am looking for.

The first one is the usage of `htop` command. As I understood, it prints the separate cores load on screen. I was not able to extract this information with one `grep` command.

I tried looking in the `htop` source code, but was not able to understand how it gets the cores usage information.

Another solution that I found involves the usage of

```
ps -A -o %cpu | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s "%"}'
```

The result is one number that represents the overall CPU usage. If I am correct, the output of macOS `ps` command, that is used here, does not provide the information about each process's core, so t is not possible to use that approach for my task.

I hope that it is possible to get such results in macOS.

Comment: This may help https://askubuntu.com/a/726661

Comment: This approach allows to get `htop` output, which could later be parsed. Unfortunately, the result contains nan% instead of the actual usage numbers. I tried to use `(sleep 5; echo q)` to wait for numbers to appear, but sadly they don't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is how you do it on Mac:

1. Put the Activity Monitor in the Dock
2. Right click on the icon > Monitors

[image]